# Python 2.7: Defining default parameters based on globals?

Tags: python-2.7, global, default-parameters

I'm writing a utility where I would like to have global variables that change the way a function operates. By default I'd like all the functions to follow one style, but in certain cases I'd also like the ability to force the way a function operates.

Say I have a file Script_Defaults.py with

```
USER_INPUT = True
```

In another python file I have many functions like this:

```
from Script_Defaults import USER_INPUT
def DoSomething(var_of_data, user_input = USER_INPUT):
    if user_input:
        ... #some code here that asks the user what to change in var_of_data
    .... # goes on to do something
```

The problem I face here is that the default parameter only loads once when the file starts.
I want to be able to set `USER_INPUT` as `False` or `True` during the run of the program. To get this behaviour I'm currently using it like this...

```
from Script_Defaults import USER_INPUT
def DoSomething(var_of_data, user_input = None):
    if user_input is None:
         user_input = USER_INPUT
    if user_input:
        ... #some code here that asks the user what to change in var_of_data
    .... # goes on to do something
```

This seems like a lot of unnecessary code, especially if I have a lot of conditions like `USER_INPUT`, and many functions that need them. Is there a better to get this functionality, or is this the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using decorators, and manipulation of a function's default arguments, you can use the following solution:

```
from change_defaults import Default, set_defaults

my_defaults = dict(USER_INPUT=0)


@set_defaults(my_defaults)
def DoSomething(var_of_data, user_input=Default("USER_INPUT")):
    return var_of_data, user_input


def main():
    print DoSomething("This")

    my_defaults["USER_INPUT"] = 1

    print DoSomething("Thing")

    my_defaults["USER_INPUT"] = 2

    print DoSomething("Actually")
    print DoSomething("Works", 3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which requires the following code:

```
# change_defaults.py

from functools import wraps

class Default(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Default, self).__init__()

        self.name = name


def set_defaults(defaults):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Backup original function defaults.
            original_defaults = f.func_defaults

            # Replace every `Default("...")` argument with its current value.
            function_defaults = []
            for default_value in f.func_defaults:
                if isinstance(default_value, Default):
                    function_defaults.append(defaults[default_value.name])
                else:
                    function_defaults.append(default_value)

            # Set the new function defaults.
            f.func_defaults = tuple(function_defaults)

            return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)

            # Restore original defaults (required to keep this trick working.)
            f.func_defaults = original_defaults

            return return_value

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

By defining the default parameters with `Default(parameter_name)` you tell the `set_defaults` decorator which value to take from the defaults dict.

Also, with a little more code (irrelevant to the solution) you can make it work like:

```
@set_defaults(my_defaults)
def DoSomething(var_of_data, user_input=Default.USER_INPUT):
    ...
```

Comment: `@set_defaults(globals())` would also work? Maybe you can modify it to use the function globals `f.func_globals`. That would be nice, too. Just a hint: put the cool use case of the solution first and then present the code.

Comment: Yes, using `@set_default(globals())` works as well. Just make sure you set your variables in the global scope (`global MY_VAR`).
You can build a solution around `f.func_globals`, but that would make it more difficult to declare the arguments.

Comment: I mean that instead of `@set_default(globals())` you just do `@default_global` and use the global stored in the function instead of `globals()`. That could be closer to the question.

Comment: You can probably do it, but it would make it harder to tell which variables you want to replace.